# Чому «Жовтогарячий» пишемо разом?

Tags: правопис, разом-дефіс-окремо

Згідно правила, назви відтінків пишемо через дефіс: *чорно-білий, яскраво-ліловий, жовтувато-червоний, біло-жовтий* пишеться через дефіс, а *жовтогарячий* разом чому так?

Comment: Додайте, будь-ласка, кілька слів про ваші особисті спроби знайти відповідь.

Comment: @ХристинаВороніна, мабуть, це одрук, але про всяк випадок: [«будь ласка»](//ukr-mova.in.ua/library/orfografiya/bud-laska) (вибачте за off-topic і прискіпливість).

Comment: @Sasha так, це одрук) дякую)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Чорно-білий, жовтувато-червоний, біло-жовтий* — це суміші кольорів. Частини слова є рівноправними (суміш чорного і білого, білого і жовтого тощо). Так само: *кисло-солодкий, весняно-літній, бавовняно-синтетичний*.

*Жовтогарячий* — це особливий вид жовтого кольору. Це не «суміш жовтого і гарячого». Аналогічно *червоногарячий*.

Джерело: моє власне трактування [§ 29 «Правопису» 2015](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil1.htm#par29).